# Print current date in English language

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

In Odoo, I'd like to print current date in English in QWeb report:

```
<span t-esc="datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d %B %Y')"/>
```

The expected behavior is : **20 January 2019**

The current behavior is: **20 janvier 2019**

What should I do to display the month in English instead of the system language (French)?

Comment: Is French your system Locale?

Comment: @Oren_C Yes, my system is in french

Comment: Always in English or just for some partners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using LOCALE

```
import locale 

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')

print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d %B %Y'))
```

Comment: Thanks,There is a way to add this directly in, qweb report?

Comment: you could try this <span t-esc="import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US'); datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d %B %Y')"/>

Comment: did that answer help?

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work, this is not a correct syntax o, can you give a python function to show current date in english?

Comment: the current date in english has the same command as you had provided. Only the locale needs to be changed as provided in the first two lines of my answer

Comment: is it a windows machine? can you try locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'english')

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_month.py", line 4, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 598, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: I guess you are on a linux machine. try en_US.utf-8 instead of en_US